# How to remove a Backend Modul of the Backend Menu in Contao

Tags: module, contao

I developed an modul for contao 3.0. In my config.php file i wrote this lines:

```
$GLOBALS['BE_MOD']['content']['modultest'] = array(
'tables' => array('tl_modultest'),
'icon'       => 'system/modules/modultest/time_go.png',
```

);

Now i have the problem, that i want to deinstall the modul. But the menupoint in the backend is still there, even if i deleted the lines above.

Can anybody help me to deactivate or delete deactivated or deinstalled modules from the backend menu ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you did not rebuild the internal cache introduced in Contao 3.0. To do that, go to **Maintenance**, then under the section **Purge** select the checkbox labeled **Purge the internal cache** and click **Purge data**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that't not the solution. I already tried that.